# Getting wrong square-root estimation

Tags: c, algorithm, square-root

I have written a program in C which is calculating for me the square root with the [heron procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots). `x` is my number, `r` is estimated value and `steps` are steps. I want to output the difference between the exact value and the value obtained by the heron method. But it seems that my function is not correct. For my calculated value I get no value. Can anyone help me?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
    
int heron (x, r, steps)
{
  int k = 0;
  double xold, xnew;
  double rel_error = 1.0;

  while(k <= steps && rel_error > 1e-4) {
    ++k;
    xnew = .5 * (xold + x / xold);
    rel_error = (xnew - xold) / xnew;
    if(rel_error < 0) 
      rel_error = -rel_error;
      xold = xnew;
    }
    printf("exact value: %.10f\n", sqrt(x));
    return (xnew);
}
    
int main()
{
  int x=4, r=10, steps=50;
  printf("%f\n", heron(x, r, steps));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `But it seems that my function is not correct` can you expand on this please?

Comment: Well, it's returning (and printing two times) the value of `sqrt(x)`, not the one calculated.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and treat them as errors. This is broken on multiple fronts. Uninitialized `xold` and the wrong return type (should be `double`, not `int`) to name a few.

Comment: `For my calculated value i get no value` what does this mean? What variable is holding your calculated value, and what does it mean for it to have "no value"?

Comment: Your `printf` statement expects a float - `"%f\n"` - but `heron` returns an `int`. Seems like that's probably a factor.

Comment: You're calculating a double value, but your return type from `heron` is `int`. Does that really look right?

Answer (score 1):

Change `int heron (x, r, steps)` to `double heron(double x, double r, int steps)`. You need to declare the types of the parameters, and the function works with floating-point values, so it ought to return `float` or `double`, not `int`, and `x` and `r` should be `double`.

Change `double xold , xnew;` to `double xold = r, xnew;`. `xold` must be initialized before it is used.

Change `return sqrt(x);` to `return xold;` to return the value that the function calculated.

Answer (score 1):

With this prefix

```
int heron (x, r, steps)
{
```

your function is a function that takes an integer `x`, another integer `r`, and a third integer `steps`.  Indeed, it also returns an integer.

The algorithm you describe can be implemented in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double heron(double x, double err)
{
    double a = x, b = 1.0;
    while (a - b > err) {
        a = (a + b)/2.0; /* arithmetic mean */
        b = x / a; /* approx to geometric mean */
    }
    return a; /* or b, depending if you want a value in excess or in defect */
}

int main()
{
        printf("heron(2.0, 1.0E-10) = %.10f\n", heron(2.0, 1.0E-10));
        printf("sqrt(2.0) = %.10f\n", sqrt(2.0));
}
```

and that will work.
Read about function parameter type definitions in one of the many references of the C programming languages, e.g. "The C programming language" from Brian Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie, for reference.

```
$ ./heron
heron(2.0, 1.0E-10) = 1.4142135624
sqrt(2.0) = 1.4142135624
$ _
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. It is clear for me now.

Comment: @JohnBlack, you should select one answer as _the selected answer_.